# Qt/C++: QTableView contextmenu and passing through information

Tags: c++, qt, signals, argument-passing

I want a contextmenu on the cells in my QTableView, so first I connected:

```
connect(ui->tblTimesheet,SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)),this,SLOT(sheetContextMenu(const QPoint &)));
```

And the slot for that connect is below:

```
void wndMyWindow::sheetContextMenu(const QPoint &pos){
    QMenu *menu = new QMenu;
    QModelIndex cell = ui->tblTimesheet->indexAt(pos);
    // Make sure the right click occured on a cell!
    if(cell.isValid()){
        QString myid=cell.sibling(cell.row(),0).data().toString();
        menu->addAction("Remove item", this, SLOT(sheetRemoveItem()));
        menu->exec(ui->tblTimesheet->mapToGlobal(pos));
    }
}
```

Which creates the menu and puts an action in the menu which calls a function when that action is clicked. However, I want to pass through the variable myid into the second slot. That slot is listed below:

```
void wndMyWindow::sheetRemoveItem(){
    qDebug("Sure I'm here, but what info do I have?");
    return;
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to do this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this regard, Qt signals/slots suck compared to callbacks and other signal/slot mechanisms.  You really can't attach extra information.

Couple things you can do though:

1. Create an object that stores the information you want to send, give it a slot and attach to the signal you want to respond to, emit a new signal with the information, attach to that signal.
2. Use the Qt signal map thingy to attach some small variation of data to a signal.
3. You can get the sender in a Qt slot.  This may be the information you need. (see the Qt docs on signals/slots).

If none of those methods work for you, sorry to say but, you're pretty much fscked.  I'm working on a method to auto-create #1 and attach to a boost::signal, which would be more powerful, but it's going to require a lot of hard work because Qt is incompatible with the C++ preprocessor and with templates.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, the more I looked around the less it looked possible- which seems pretty stupid because isn't the whole point of a context menu to be able to perform some action on a specific widget? If I wanted a global action I'd use a regular menu or some other type of interface widget!  What I went with was giving my form a private member QModelIndex lastCellRightClicked; and I set it in the void wndMyWindow::sheetContextMenu(const QPoint &pos) slot and then use it in the void wndMyWindow::sheetRemoveItem() slot. Good Enough™.

Comment: If you just want to implement some specific thing for a specific menu item the what you want to do is attach to the item's QAction.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the previous answer, I realized that you can actually attach some data on to the sender. I do it in my code.

Every objects that inherits from QObject has "setProperty()". Here you can set some data before it starts sending signals. In one of my slots I do the following:

```
qobject_cast<QAction*>(sender())->property("index").toInt()
```

This allows me to attach an index to my action.

Comment: Or you can just use the QAction::setData() / QAction::data() methods.